# Machine Learning over Finite Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, optimization, finite-fields, machine-learning, data-mining

My question is if machine learning over finite fields is a sensible idea, or if there is any literature regarding this. By that I mean, given some function with inputs and outputs on a finite field and some training data from this function, does it make sense to apply machine learning to learn this function, i.e., predict test data from this function (i.e., data not from the training set)? An example might be trying to learn the discrete log function over a finite field with very large prime order. I would appreciate any insight anyone may have.

I am not sure whether or not it does. One point against the idea is that while notions such as greater than, less than, limit, etc. exist over real numbers, for which there exists ordering among elements, there does not exist ordering in the elements of finite fields in the same sense and so those notions do not have the same meaning.

Thus, I am not sure how to develop a loss function, for example, since I'm not sure of a way to quantify how far a prediction is from the truth. I'm also not sure how such a model could be trained, since derivatives don't exist over finite fields in the same way. Also, the concepts of signal and noise are not the same; I would expect all training data to be a precisely correct manifestation of some function, therefore all signal.

Comment: From a Bayesian point of view, if you start with a uniform prior over all possible functions from a finite set to another finite set, then each data point is independent, so it is not possible to generalize from training data at all. To fix this you need a prior over functions which is *not* uniform, e.g. some reason to believe that your data is more likely to be generated by "simpler" functions than "complex" functions, for some value of "simple" (e.g. a polynomial of low degree). Then you could imagine updating such a prior given some data points.

Comment: I don't know anything about machine learning, but your problem description reminds me of a problem faced by coding theorists. When an error correcting code with symbols in a finite field is used in a channel, where reliability information about the received symbols is available, the decoder should strive to take advantage. The only algebraic scheme even partially capable of doing that uses polynomials in such a way that reliability of a value is becomes multiplicity of a zero of a polynomial. The higher the multiplicity, the more reliable.

Comment: (cont'd) I don't know if that would work at all in your problem. I know that Alex Vardy and Ralf Kötter worked on it, and they built a chip performing such decoding of Reed-Solomon codes at UIUC. Sadly both the principal investigators died (relatively) young. Anyway, if it sounds at all like something that might help your cause, do search for their paper. IIRC ideas from Madhu Sudan's list decoding algorithm played a role, but I may be conflating two related problems here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that's a good point, and something I have wondered myself. For typical machine learning over real numbers, do you know if there is some implicit prior? For example, using a neural network to approximate a function over the reals?


Further, I wonder if, even over the reals, having all training data exactly correct (i.e., no noise), causes any problems for say, a neural network.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan also, a finite field does have structure among elements (i.e., operations that relate the elements in a specific way) as opposed to some finite set, so I don't know if that makes a difference.